# Android - How do I fade an image in?

Tags: android, fadein, fade, fadeout, tween

Okay so I don't understand how I'm supposed to do this.

All I want it to do is have an image fade on top of my game.

This method is in my MainGame class which extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback

**Here is my fadein.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="3000" 
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>`

**I've tried:**

> public void Animation() {
>   ImageView myImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.block1);
>   Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fadein);
>   myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation); 
>   }
>
> **The method loadAnimation(Context, int) in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the arguments (MainGame, int)**

**as well as**

> `public void Animation() {
>   ImageView myImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
>   Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
>   myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
>   }`
>
> **The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type MainGame**

I've also tried putting the Animation method in it's own class called fade that extends Activity and creating an animation object called Fade in my MainGame class and calling it in a method by

Fade.Animation();

Which I can compile and run but it crashes as soon as the method containing that runs.

Perhaps someone could provide me with a basic example or a tutorial? Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getApplicationContext(), use the Context object from your Activity.  This is probably handed to your SurfaceView in its constructor.  You can save a reference to this in the View's constructor and use it when the View needs a context.

Comment: Yeah I believe the context is handed to the SurfaceView in the constructor with **super(context);**   so I changed getApplicationContext() to **MainGame.super.getContext()** but the app still crashes. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong still...

Comment: In your SurfaceView create an instance variable to hold the context that you get in your constructor.  Use that variable in place of those methods.  Also, could you copy and post the stacktrace of your crash?

Comment: It says AndroidRuntime java.lang.NullPointerException at the method I called it in.